# Show Webform Confirmation message in popup window

Tags: 7, webforms

In my drupal7 site i have buit a contact form using Webform.

I like to do two things.

1. I want to show webform confirmation message in popup window.I have searched net found some popup module but the problem is they all belongs to drupal 6
2. When i submit the webform i am getting this error message

> Notice: Undefined index: #webform_component in theme_webform_display_select()
>   (line 522 of /var/www/www.example.com/www/example/sites/all/modules/webform/components/select.inc).

Can you help me to solve this two things.Thank you friends

Comment: maybe colorbox module might help you. Also, check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/show-forms-in-a-modal-window

Answer (score 2):

Without doing any coding to achieve this you could use a module like [Purr Messages](http://drupal.org/project/purr_messages) and then adjust the style of it's output with CSS, this would apply to all system messages though..

Otherwise like zerocoolhotone mentioned, the simple dialog is an effective way of achieving this too.

Regarding your second question, it's a bug/issue with webform, if memory serves me right you can use the development snapshot to overcome it temporarily until they roll it out.

Answer (score 2):

you can look for simple eric martin plugin
which gives a simple js library which you can put at module level or theme level
and you have to add js snippet to tell eric matin plaugin to pull the content for a url which should be your confirmation page.

Answer (score 1):

you can  try this: [Simple Dialog](http://drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module

i hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply friend.NOw i check it out and leave u reply...Do you have any idea about that error message?

Comment: did you use any module of drupal 6 , if use please uninstall first cause its conflict drupla7

Comment: no i have not used any module of drupal 6....When i googled it it says it is a webform module bug...

Answer (score 0):

all you need dude is to install [Nice messages module](https://www.drupal.org/project/nicemessages) and the confirmation message will show as popup message thats it ;) .