# How to load add comment form in light box or any other pop up

Tags: javascript

Want to load add comment form in light box or any other java script pop please help me how should i approach this

Comment: please use search, e.g http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/how-do-i-create-a-form-in-a-modal-dialog-with-drupal-7

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/modal_forms