# How can I display a custom form in a popup?

Tags: 6, forms, javascript

I have created a form in my custom module, and I want to show it in a popup. I used the [Modal Forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module, but it has some issues.

How can I display a custom form in a popup?

Comment: You can go through [Show forms in a modal window](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/show-forms-in-a-modal-window).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with the [Lightbox](https://drupal.org/project/lightbox2) module, for example using the following.

```
<a href="calc.html" rel='lightframe'><img src="sites/all/images/calc.png" /></a>
```

Don't forget to add `rel='lightframe'`. See this [page](http://www.richtown.ae/) at the bottom, and click on "Mortage calculator."

The other option is the [Popup Filter](https://drupal.org/project/popup_filter) module which allows builders to popup tooltip-like text, nodes, blocks, menus, forms, views and PHP-generated content. Even you can mention the block to appear in popup window. And it has the option to popup the login form, register form etc.

Also look at the [Popups API (Ajax Dialogs)](https://drupal.org/project/popups) module.

> API for building modal ajax dialogs. Its focus is on putting forms inside of ajax popup dialogs.
>   Current example can present pages as popups (of the lightbox type). This is amazingly useful for things like confirmation pages. And the best part is it can be applied retroactively to a page without needing to modify the generating module, and (of course) it degrades gracefully.

Comment: Form is showing correctly in lightbox but how to close the popup and redirect on thankyou page after submit the form?

Comment: See this www.richtown.ae at the bottom, and click on "Mortage calculator." it shows the close button, i don't know why not showing in yours and also if you click outside the form it will close or by pressing the Esc key. For redirect - i don't know what form you are using - are you using webform or php or html ?

Comment: No no close button is appearing fine. I am using drupal's form api. When I submit the form it opens the thank you page in popup. I used `$form_state['redirect']` to redirect on the thankyou page.

Comment: So your redirecting working right ?

Comment: I tried to put this in my submit function `window.parent.Lightbox.end();` but it is not adding the js.

Comment: It is redirecting in popup itself. And I want to redirect it on the page.

Comment: Sorry i never implemented that, you have to ask separate question

Comment: May be this will help you https://drupal.org/node/575540

Comment: not working still redirecting in popup.