# how do I open a custom module form in colorbox popup?

Tags: 7, views, forms

I am creating a form in custom module, and I need to show this form in a view. How do I show this form in a color-box popup?

I have created a custom block to render this form, but I don't understand how to show this form in a view page, inside a popup.

Comment: checkout [Show forms in a modal window](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18842/show-forms-in-a-modal-window) and [how can i display my custom form in popup in drupal 7? (duplicate)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163379/how-can-i-display-my-custom-form-in-popup-in-drupal-7)

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to use [chaos tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) for modal popup form. Its easy to implement and integrate into Drupal 7. I already used in my several sits.

You can find a great example of Ctools modal form at [here](http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/insert-form-pop-modal-ctools-and-drupal-7)